# How to create a Function that returns a Promise type dynamically

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am in an scenario where I know what kind of data will be returned from fetching to an API,

I have the following function

```
const fetchingData = async (url: string, options?: Object): Promise<any> => {
  const res = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

This function returns a Promise of Type any, but how could I create a promise that can return no matter the type im passing through here Promise in order to have a typed response?

I was thinking in something like this example

```
interface One{
...
}
interface Two{
...
}

const fetchingData = async (url: string, options?: Object): Promise<One | Two> => {
  const res = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

but this approach is not quite good because any time you fetch to another data source you will have to create a new interface and add it into the helper function.

So, How Could I get this fetchingData function more dynamic when returning a typed Promise?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Comment: Does the return type in the typed Promise depends on any input or the context calling it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with two possible solutions. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better design approach according to me would be to create methods with specific names instead of having one generic method. Your function name should tell what it does. It has to be specific. I would have gone with the following design.

```js
class ApiService {

  // method to fetch states from the API call
  private static fetchState(url: string, options: StateOptions): Promise<State[]> {
      return ApiService.fetchData(url, options);
  }
  
  // private method, only accessible in ApiService class
  private static async fetchData(url: string, options?: any): Promise<any> {
      const res = await fetch(url, options);
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
  }

}
```

It is not good to put all your API calls in a single class, you can categorise them by extending the `APIService` class by making the `fetchData` method `protected`.

The benefits of the above approach

1. Interfaces for options and return type can be defined
2. function names refer to the actual API call, helps in debugging purpose and increases the readability of code.
3. Special cases like data pre-processing before making the API call, or defining the constants can be done in the specific function. For example, if your state API requires that you pass language as `en`, it is better to hardcode this in your `ApiService.fetchState` method rather than passing it into the argument with each function call.

I've taken the object-oriented approach, you can implement the same using the functional approach as well. But the main point is that, do not reuse the generic method everywhere in your code, you will run into issues while scaling and maintenance will be very difficult.

This is my personal opinion from my own experience.

Now, coming to your question.

**How to create a Function that returns a Promise type dynamically?**

You can do so by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in Typescript

```js
async function fetchData<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    const result: any = {};
    return result;
}

interface State {
    code: string;
    name: string;
}

interface Country {
    code: string;
    name: string;
}

const fetchStates = fetchData<State[]>("/fetch/state");
const fetchCountry = fetchData<Country[]>("/fetch/country");
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLwKbKgCwBFhlgAeAFQD4AKBAJwBsAuGEZe1CAcwEpWACvXQBbVCGyUqMAN4BYAFAxlMKJnYx62EAkbJWwCGBgBeWQF8A3IpWbcDLFp17rC84sVdk2enGBRsGABlUm9ZGxU1ABNsVnZOHldbCGARWLYOLm5XdwVPCG9ff0CAYXQkDmN5JUj0GLjMxIjlFLSGhOzFXMU1CA04XAIQkm1THDwiEnJh7wBtAF1aACIAegGJlfYRpd5XXv7B-DKK+mMzdYJiUjJjgtOF5bXDlbUTsB3XRSA)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. If you want to add another type you can just change or add in type T.
[Check Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlQG4AoAYwHtMUoAzCYOgCy2wBEAhsAEIoApCEx0oACiKoANgC5kaXgBooDMMHRMkAfhUB5MgCsIdYAEoVABVQMS6JBAA8MAHwJvAbxpQUIzMwFCoEEiiAgDuAuih7Jxccoqa2rr61rSBwSwAJkIiiDFxoeFIAHRmSEwyWQFhHPKYUAXCtAC%20VEA)

```
 type T = string | number;
    const fetchingData = async (url: string, options?: Object): Promise<T> => {
      const res = await fetch(url, options);
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    };
```